# My dropdown button in my navbar is upper than other items

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

Being used to using navbars from UI Frameworks, this time I wanted to create a navbar not dependent on any framework, that's why I followed a tutorial on the internet, unfortunately when I tried to decrease the font-size of the links, this problem appeared. My dropdown button containing "profile" is upper than my other links, I would like it to be aligned with the others.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap');

html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-family:'Nunito',sans-serif;
}

.nav {
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .nav a {
     float: left;
     display: block;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 12px;
}
 .nav a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
 .nav .active {
     color: #000;
     font-weight: 600;
}
 .nav .icon {
     display: none;
}
 .nav .dropdown {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
 .nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
 .nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
     font-size: 12px;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     padding: 14px 16px;
     background-color: inherit;
     margin: 0;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #fff;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content a {
     float: none;
     color: #9b9b9b;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
     transition: 0.4s ease;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="topnav">
        <a href="/" class="active">For You</a>
        <a href="/">Discover</a>
        <a href="/">Jobs</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/">My profile</a>
                <a href="/">My projects</a>
                <a href="/">Settings</a>
                <a href="/">Help</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

See? "Profile" is upper than other links

Answer (score 3):

The trouble, is that the font-family for your button is not being set, it will be inheriting the native front family for button.

Here i hjave simply added it to your styles to assign it, but you can do it in a more elegant way, by making a "link" class maybe...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap');

html,body, .dropbtn {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-family:'Nunito',sans-serif;
}

.nav {
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .nav a {
     float: left;
     display: block;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 12px;
}
 .nav a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
 .nav .active {
     color: #000;
     font-weight: 600;
}
 .nav .icon {
     display: none;
}
 .nav .dropdown {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
 .nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
 .nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
     font-size: 12px;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     padding: 14px 16px;
     background-color: inherit;
     margin: 0;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #fff;
     min-width: 160px;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content a {
     float: none;
     color: #9b9b9b;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
     transition: 0.4s ease;
}
 .nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="topnav">
        <a href="/" class="active">For You</a>
        <a href="/">Discover</a>
        <a href="/">Jobs</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/">My profile</a>
                <a href="/">My projects</a>
                <a href="/">Settings</a>
                <a href="/">Help</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```